# Is the time complexity of this function O(N)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of this function? The function returns minimum value in the array. I think it's `O(N)` but I can't prove it. Any help would be appreciated!

```
int[] foo(int arr[], int N)
{
   int k = 1;
   while(k < N)
   {
      for(int i = 0; i+k<N; i+=2*k) 
      {
         if(arr[k] > arr[i+k])
         {
            swap(arr[i], arr[k+i]); //swap values in arr[i] and arr[k+1]
         }
      }
      k = k*2;
   }

   return arr[0];
 }
```

Comment: It seems to be `O(NlogN)`

Comment: Please improve your question

Comment: It looks like O(N) to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `O(N)`.

It may seem like `O(NlogN)` at a first glance, but:

- 1st inner for loop: `i = 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, ...` i.e. `N/2` operations
- 2nd inner for loop: `i = 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, ...` i.e. `N/4` operations
- 3rd inner for loop: `i = 0, 8, 16, 24, 32, ...` i.e. `N/8` operations
- 4th inner for loop: `i = 0, 16, 32, 48, 64, ...` i.e. `N/16` operations
- etc.

`N/2 + N/4 + N/8 + N/16 + ... = N(1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 ...) = N`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Comment: Thanks! So the outer while loop which determines the number of times the inner loop runs is lgN and including the lgN, would the runtime be approximate to N x (sum of 1/2^i from i = 0 to i = lgN)?

Comment: @JJTO No. The TOTAL runtime is `O(N)`. The equation `N/2 + N/4 + N/8 + N/16 + ...` comes from adding up all iterations of the outer while loop. Thus multiplying that by `logN` would be nonsensical.